# @ManagedProperty Managed bean between scopos alias

Tags: java, jsf

I'm not able to inject a ManagedBean with scope view in another well with same scope, is it possible?

**Example:**

**CarBean**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="carBean")
public class CarBean{}
```

**EngineBean**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class EngineBean {
@ManagedProperty(value="#{carBean}")
private CarBean carBean;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is and don't forget to add getter and setter for carBean like this

```
public CarBean getCarBean(){
    return carBean;
}
public void setCarBean(CarBean carBean){
    this.carBean = carBean;
}
```